# What's the c# equivalent of java's Eventlist

Tags: c#, java, list

and doing some kind of mapping between a java code to a c# code, and i've crossed over the

```
EventList yourlist;
```

in java, what i would like to know, what the equivalent of it in c#?? and will the normal lists in c# do relatively the same? or there's something quite specific for java's EventList in C#.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain the requirements in plain English, not in code in another programming language. [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362).

Comment: It seems like an `EventList` class is part of several Java *libraries*, but not of the core language and class library. So this question is rather useless as it is, because no one really knows what the heck you are using there.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: We now know that the `EventList` in question is an [interface in the SSJ library](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/ssj/doc/html/umontreal/iro/lecuyer/simevents/eventlist/EventList.html). It's not clear why this isn't just a generic interface, given that it doesn't look like there's anything event-specific in the interface. (This gives me concerns over the design over the SSJ library, but maybe the rest of it is well-designed.)

If you're trying to port code which uses SSJ, you'll either need to port the SSJ library itself, or find some equivalent.

I wouldn't suggest doing *either* of those until you're more familiar with C# and .NET though. Learn the basics of the language and the platform first, then you'll be in a much better position to port code later.

---

It's not a good idea to port Java code *directly*, member for member. Instead, you should port it *idiomatically*. Work out the *concepts* that the Java code is trying to model, and then work out the most appropriate way of modelling the same ideas in C#. Sometimes the code will look similar, sometimes it won't.

Java doesn't have any *language* support for events - presumably `EventList` is something similar (although it's not part of the core Java libraries, so we can't tell for sure). In C# you'd usually just use an event, e.g.

```
public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
```

See [my article on delegates and events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx) for more information about them.

Of course, if `EventList` isn't related to event handlers, you'll want to do something different - we'd need more context to be able to help you more.

Comment: It seems like `EventList` gets used as an event queue in certain simulation libraries. In that case you're already lost anyway if you want to model it with directly-available language tools, as in simulation it's the event queues that make most of the difference in performance.

Comment: Mr, jon skeet i guess this link tells you exactly what the EventList does in the java language http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/ssj/doc/html/umontreal/iro/lecuyer/simevents/eventlist/EventList.html i really hope that you can find this link helpful

Comment: @MSpawn986: You don't understand - that's not "in the Java language" - it's part of a completely separate library. You need to differentiate between *language* and *libraries*. There are probably *lots* of `EventList` implementations in different projects. It looks like this is an "event" in terms of scheduling, rather than the C# style of event. In this case, `EventList` is an interface in the first place. Are you trying to port the SSJ library, or just something that *uses* it?

Comment: i really do understand the differences between the language and the libraries, what i'm interested in is the queuing theory, i want to write a program that depicts the principles of the MM1 in c#, and as i stated earlier i'm quite a newbie in c#, so i was looking for clues how to build it in c#, and the closest thing that i found was a code in java, now this code used the EventList that i'm asking you guys about it, and that was the way the it was declared        public static EventList futureEventList;

Comment: @MSpawn986: If you understand the differences between the language and the libraries, why did you repeatedly refer to an interface from a particularly library as "java's EventList"? Have you read the documentation for `EventList`? It's just an interface. If you want to use a library like SSJ, you should look for a library like that in .NET - it's not part of the standard library in either Java *or* C#. I would actually recommend that you learn the basics of C# and .NET before trying to port any code though.